# ICC Error 1072896749

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet

I am getting this error (in taskroute log) while trying to ingest documents from ICC (IBM Content Collector v2.1.x) with xml as metadata file. Can anyone shed more light on "Whitespace is not allowed at this location." error?

```
 2011-09-12T18:39:37Z   Error   An error occurred while evaluating the task route 'M1 TR Docs': Task Method 'ibm.ctms.filesystem.metadata' failed for entity with id 'd:\icc_migration\conventional_pm\test.xml': Status=error; Message='Error -1072896749 at 22:22 - "Whitespace is not allowed at this location." - D:\ICC_Migration\Conventional_PM\test.xml'Reason: Task Method 'ibm.ctms.filesystem.metadata' failed for entity with id 'd:\icc_migration\conventional_pm\test.xml': Status=error; Message='Error -1072896749 at 22:22 - "Whitespace is not allowed at this location." - D:\ICC_Migration\Conventional_PM\test.xml'    ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskRouteEvaluator::SubmitRoute (taskrouteevaluator.cpp:427)    0x820   Stack Trace: (class ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskStatusException)    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskRoutingException::TaskRoutingException (taskrouting.cpp:11),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskStatusException::TaskStatusException (taskrouting.cpp:88),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskMethodManager::checkTaskStatus (taskmethodmanager.cpp:610),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskMethodManager::InvokeTaskMethod (taskmethodmanager.cpp:730),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskRouteEvaluator::invokeTaskMethod (taskrouteevaluator.cpp:255),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskRouteEvaluator::SubmitRoute (taskrouteevaluator.cpp:375),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::TaskRouteEngine::SubmitEntity (taskrouteengine.cpp:475),    at ibm::ctms::taskrouting::SubmissionTask::Execute (submissiontask.cpp:44),    at ibm::ctms::core::threads::ThreadPoolImplementation::TaskThread::Execute (threadpool.cpp:214),    at ATL::CThreadPool<ibm::ctms::core::threads::ThreadPoolImplementation::TaskThread,ATL::CRTThreadTraits,ATL::Win32WaitTraits>::ThreadProc (atlutil.h:1386),    at ATL::CThreadPool<ibm::ctms::core::threads::ThreadPoolImplementation::TaskThread,ATL::CRTThreadTraits,ATL::Win32WaitTraits>::WorkerThreadProc (atlutil.h:1404),    at MSVCR80.dll:0x29ba,    at MSVCR80.dll:0x2a46,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it. The XML that I was trying to use had a tag like this.

```
<Company name>Test & Company</Company Name>
```

And of course, it did not like the "&" symbol there. I enclosed it in CDATA tag and it was fixed. What was mysterious though was the disconnect between the type of error and error message ICC was throwing.